# No option to add web services in Eclipse 4.5

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, web-services, wcf

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709160/consume-wcf-service-in-java-using-eclipse) and the answer came back to refer to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777036/Consuming-WCF-Service-in-Java-Client?msg=5100438#xx5100438xx). However something seems to have changed in Eclipse since that article was written. There is no menu option New > Web Services > select Web Service Client in Eclipse 4.5.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: There are several different downloads of Eclipse, you need to use one that has the Web development code included.

Comment: What the dickens? Why? I am not creating a web project. I just need to consume a WCF service in an application.